# c++ Copy Parameter Value

Tags: c++

I want to specify the value pointed to by the parameter after dynamic memory allocation.
But I get an error. How can I solve this?

```
class Point
{
private:
     int *x;

public:

    Point(int *a)
    {
        x=int new;
        x=a;
    }
    ~Point()
    {
        if(x)
            delete x;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int c=2;
    Point p(&c);
    p.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please add error . int new ? it should be new int;

Comment: why does your class contain a pointer and not an actual value?

Comment: Rule of 3/5/0 is also broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is just a small typo: you have to write `new int` instead of `int new`. However, your code has a logic error, and that's this line:

```cpp
x = a;
```

As `x` and `a` are both pointer types, you assign the pointer - and not the value it points to - to `x`. This way, the original value of `x` - the integer which was just allocated - is lost, and in the destructor, you're going to `delete` `a`! To fix this, you have to assign *the value `a` points to* to the *integer `x` points to*. This is done with the dereference operator:

```cpp
*x = *a;
```

Furthermore, use the dereference operator in `print()`:

```cpp
cout << *x;
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax int new is wrong it should be new int

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
class Point
{
private:
    int* x;

public:

    Point(int* a)
    {
        x = new int;
        *x = *a;
    }
    ~Point()
    {
        if (x)
            delete x;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << x;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int c = 2;
    Point p(&c);
    p.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
explicit Point(int a)
{
    x=new int(a);
}
~Point()
{
    delete x;
}
```

and then `Point p(c);` in `main`.

The ctor is explicit in order to avoid surprising implicit conversions. Passing an int rather than a pointer to int is safer - no need for a pointer check and no risk of crashing if you don't check and pass in a NULL pointer. Avoid unnecessary complexity when you can. Also there is no need to check for a NULL pointer when calling delete.

As it stands this code also has problems with the ownership of `x`.

For instance, if you have

```
int main()
{
    int c = 2;
    Point p(&c);
    p.print();
    Point p2(p); // copy added here
}
```

Then there will be a double delete of `x` - a serious error that could cause heap corruption and a crash.

I appreciate that you may be using dynamic memory allocation as a learning exercise, but it would make the code simpler, faster and safer to not use it. Just make `x` an int. Then you don't need a destructor.